Refresh the access token using redux-toolkit asyncThunks
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axiosInstance from "../utils/axiosInstance";

export const logoutUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "users/logoutUser",
  async (_, { rejectWithValue, dispatch }) => {
    try {
      const response = await axiosInstance.post("/users/logout");
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response.status);
      if (error.response.status === 401) {
        try {
          await dispatch(refreshUserToken());

          const retryResponse = await dispatch(logoutUser());
          return retryResponse;
        } catch (refreshError) {
          return rejectWithValue(refreshError.message);
        }
      } else {
        return rejectWithValue(error.message);
      }
    }
  }
);

export const refreshUserToken = createAsyncThunk(
  "users/refreshUserToken",
  async (_, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const response = await axiosInstance.post("/users/refresh-token");
      console.log("refreshToken->", response.data);
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.message);
    }
  }
);

const initialState = {
  user: {},
  status: "idle",
  error: null,
};

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder
      .addCase(logoutUser.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "loading";
      })
      .addCase(logoutUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "success";
        console.log("case f logout->", action.payload); // log statement
        state.user = {};
      })
      .addCase(logoutUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.error = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(refreshUserToken.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "loading";
      })
      .addCase(refreshUserToken.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "success";
        console.log("case f refreshToken->", action.payload); // log statement
      })
      .addCase(refreshUserToken.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.error = action.payload;
      });
  },
});

export const getUserState = (state) => state.user.status;
export const getUserError = (state) => state.user.error;
export const getUser = (state) => state.user.user;

export const {} = userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice.reducer;

below is my axios instance.
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:8082/api",
    withCredentials: true
});

I am new to Redux-Toolkit, so I'm confused. In the logoutUser asyncThunk I'm checking if the error code I receive is 401 (access toke expired), then I'm making a request for a refresh token by calling the refreshUserToken thunk inside the logoutUser thunk, but that is causing the logoutThunk to run twice.
How can I correct this? Or is there a better way to handle refresh of the token with asyncThunks?
Note: I'm using cookies to send and receive access and refresh token from the server.

Instead of re-dispatching the logoutUser action which runs the Thunk action at least one additional time you could re-call just the endpoint.
Example:
export const logoutUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "users/logoutUser",
  async (_, { rejectWithValue, dispatch }) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axiosInstance.post("/users/logout");
      return data;
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error.response.status);
      if (error.response.status === 401) {
        try {
          // Attempt token refresh, unwrap result
          await dispatch(refreshUserToken()).unwrap();

          // Retry original request
          const { data } = await axiosInstance.request(error.config);;
          return data;
        } catch(refreshError) {
          return rejectWithValue(refreshError.message);
        }
      } else {
        return rejectWithValue(error.message);
      }
    }
  }
);

To get away from implementing this retry behavior all over the place you could try using a response interceptor to abstract and handle the retry logic.
Example:
axiosInstance.js
import axios from 'axios';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8082/api',
  withCredentials: true,
});

export default axiosInstance;

userSlice.js
export const logoutUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "users/logoutUser",
  async (_, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axiosInstance.post("/users/logout");
      return data;
    } catch(error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.message);
    }
  }
);

main.jsx
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import App from './App.jsx'
import axiosInstance from './utils/axiosInstance';
import { store } from './app/store';
import { refreshUserToken } from './features/userSlice';

// Setup response interceptors for auth retry/token refresh
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => response,
  async (error) => {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
      // Attempt token refresh, unwrap result
      await store.dispatch(refreshUserToken()).unwrap();

      // Retry original request
      return axiosInstance.request(error.config);
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
);


I tried using the interceptors like you mentioned above, but as soon as I import the store
I immediately get an error:
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'userReducer' before initialization

@Abinash Ah, likely a dependency cycle between the file creating the store importing the slice reducer, the axiosInstance file importing store, and the slice file importing the axiosInstance. You can create a separate file outside these three that should be able to safely import both the store and axiosInstance and instantiate the interceptors that is just imported somewhere in the app, preferably near the root, or just do this logic in the root container where you likely render the Redux Provider where you are importing the store already. Does this make sense?

I have stored store, userSlice, axiosInstance in different files.
below is the link to the demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-y232du?file=src%2Futils%2FaxiosInstance.js

@Abinash Right, that much with those three files is expected. Now try to move the store and refreshUserToken action import, and axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(..... from the axiosInstance file somewhere else so the dependency cycle is eliminated. I moved these into your main.jsx file and the page appeared to load and render after that. Is there a way to test this flow in your sandbox?

Thank you for the help, I have moved the "axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use" inside the main.jsx file and implemented it directly in the file, and just before that I'm importing the axiosInstance and store from a different file. Everything is working now. Moving the "axiosInstance.interceptors" to a new file (not main.jsx) and importing axiosInstance there with the store, doesn't work either, the interceptor doesn't execute in that case.

@Abinash If you do that in a separate file, say axiosInterceptors.js, then you'll just need to import that file so it's code is executed, i.e. import "./axiosInterceptors";. Does this make sense?

I didn't import the file in the previous try, it works after importing the file. Thank you for the help.
